# openpyxl append row to list and then copy list to new sheet

Tags: python, openpyxl

I need to copy the row value in the iteration and copy the values to a newly created sheet - everything is working peroperly there is no issue but I need to add the additional code - see commented code

```
import os, openpyxl

os.chdir('d:\\python')
xlFile = 'Data01.xlsx'

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(xlFile)

sheet = wb['Sheet1']

salesperson = []
saleslist = []

for i in range(sheet.max_row):
    i += 1
    cellVal = sheet.cell(i, 65).value
    #rowVal = row value
    if not cellVal.startswith(' '):
         if cellVal not in salesperson:
             salesperson.append(cellVal)
             #saleslist.append(rowVal)

for cellVal in salesperson:
    wb.create_sheet(cellVal)
    saleSheet = wb[cellVal]
    #copy saleslist items to the newly created sheet

wb.save('file2.xlsx')
```

[Turn Unique Values into sheetnames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2RwB.png)
[Save their respective row vales to the new sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUgU1.png)

Comment: You also need to share with us what is the issue, or what isn't working. Also, please notice you are changing your loop index (`i += 1`) manually mid iteration.

Comment: The code is working properly (without i += 1 I get ValueError: Row or column values must be at least 1) - what I am missing is the logic to copy the rows value in the first iteration, append it to list saleslist[] and then add those values to the newly created sheets matching the cellVal value and copy the list value to it.

Comment: Your code is not working properly, your `i` is `1`,`3`,`5` etc. If you want it to start from `1` just pass to `range` the starting point, i.e. - `range(1, sheet.max_row)`. As for the rest I will answer in a while.

Comment: And please edit and update the question with all the data of what you are trying to achieve and what is not working for you. Do you need that extra list or are you just trying to copy cells to a new sheet?

Comment: Thank you for the manual iteration change midpoint feedback.

Comment: I've added 2 screenshots that might explain it better. Hopefully it helps

Comment: See new answer, I think that is what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, so one way you can go about doing it is:

1. iterate over the rows
2. check for the cell value in column `B`
3. if no sheet exists by that name -> create sheet and add data
4. else add at the correct sheet `to max_row + 1`

Now we can translate that to code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

wb = load_workbook('example.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
temp_ws = None

for row_number, row_cells in enumerate(wb.iter_rows(min_row=2), 1):
    # Iterate over rows skiping the header one
    name = ws[f'B{row_number}'].value  # Find the item in the row
    if name not in wb.sheetnames:
        # Check if item doesn't have a sheet and create one
        temp_ws = wb.create_sheet(name)
    
    else:
        # If item has a sheet add a new row to that sheet
        temp_ws = wb[name]

    if temp_ws.max_row != 1:
        # If max row is one (empty sheet) write to it
        new_row = temp_ws.max_row+1
    
    else:
        # select a new empty row
        new_row = temp_ws.max_row

    for column, cell in enumerate(row_cells, 1):
        # Add data to new row
        ws_temp.cell(row=new_row, column=column, value=cell.value)

wb.save('example')
```

Do notice this will not work if the sheets has been modified before as `max_row` might not be the first new row but the first row with `None`. If needed you can adjust this.